# Indeterminate circle progress bar on android is white, despite colorAccent color

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I'm unable to figure out how to change the color of the indeterminate circle progress bar on API-21. I've made sure that my colorAccent is set correctly. My understanding is that the system should take from colorAccent and tint the ProgressBar accordingly. Any idea what could be going wrong?

app/src/main/res/layout-v21/fragment_story_comments.xml

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="visible"/>
```

app/src/main/res/values/themes.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

app/src/main/res/values/colors.xml

```
<color name="colorAccent">#ff5722</color>
<color name="colorPrimary">#ff5722</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#e64a19</color>
```

Comment: What are your target, minimum and compile sdk versions?

Comment: ````
     minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
````

all code can be seen here: https://github.com/dinosaurwithakatana/hacker-news-android/blob/master/app/build.gradle

Answer (score 98, accepted):

*Note: This only works from Android 5.0 (Lollipop) and up, as per the original request. For older Android versions you'll have to replace the ProgressBar's progressDrawable.*

Expanding upon Liam's answer, I managed to get this working on XML using the indeterminateTint flag.

Apparently to get it to work, you need to set the indeterminate and indeterminateTintMode flags.

The mode is a bit of mystery for me. I tried all of them but only got the expected results with src_in and src_atop. I don't know what those modes actually do, so if anyone can expand on this I'd be grateful.

In any case this should work:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:indeterminateTint="#F00"
    android:indeterminateTintMode="src_in" />
```

Comment: I think it refers to PorterDuff blend modes.

Comment: I've been searching around a lot for this!!!! this is actually the simplest and the fastest answer ever!!!!!!

Comment: To the people saying this doesn't work on API < 21, the original question was asking specifically about Lollipop. If you want to change the colour on previous versions, you'll have to replace the drawable.
I've edited my response to make this clear at the top.

Comment: This is very handy in the case where you are showing an indeterminate progress bar on a background that is the same color as your accent color. (which looks fine on pre lollipop devices)

Comment: For lower versions than 21 you can use @bapho suggestion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33276760/312161

Comment: Awesome, You saved me

Answer (score 22):

this works for lower versions of android, too:

```
if (progBar.getIndeterminateDrawable() != null) {
        progBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.accent), android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

I managed to change the colour of the ProgressBar on API 21 programatically from the green, to white like this:

```
mProgressBar.getIndeterminateDrawable().setColorFilter(new LightingColorFilter(0xFF000000, 0xFFFFFF));
```

However, I still can't figure out how to do it in XML, but hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: Good one. I tried to find a way in XML too but couldn't. I guess it should be android:indeterminateTint, but it takes a color state list. I tried with a new color for the default state and it didn't work. I don't know what states are used, there are a bunch of them and I'm lazy, so maybe someone can figure it out.

Answer (score 8):

You should set a color for activated controls in your theme:

```
 <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/accent</item>
```

This works only for Android 5.0+

Comment: correct current one, colorAccent doesnt work anymore